# Yank and hold first line; copy hold space to pattern space using SED

Tags: sed

I am trying to use `h` and `G` to yank the first line in a file, and then paste the text to a pattern space at the end of all the other lines.

Input:

```
01JAN2018
00:00-00:15    0.00     DATE 
00:30-00:45    0.00     DATE
```

Output:

```
00:00-00:15    0.00     01JAN2018
00:30-00:45    0.00     01JAN2018
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Excellent minimalist definition of your problem!. But please edit your Q to include you best attempt to solve your problem. It sounds like you're close. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '1h;1d;2,${G;s/DATE\s*//}'
```

---

## Description

`1h` - hold 1st line

`1d` - Do not print 1st line

`2,$`... - From 2nd line to end

`G` - Join 1st line and pattern (current) line

`s/DATE\s*///` - Remove DATE, whtespace and newline

Comment: There is no need for the range or  curly brackets as after the first line every other line is in the range `2,$`.

Comment: It does replace `Date`, but the output shows the date on the following line instead of being placed the right of the other data. How can I keep the date on the same line so that it will look like the example in my question? Thx.

Comment: @potong - do mean everything in the braces is not needed? or do you mean to remove the braces themselves and leave all the content?

Comment: @985ranch `sed '1h;1d;G;s/DATE\s*//' file` is sufficient. `1d` terminates any further processing of line 1.